# Unable to mount root via NFS

Tags: dhcp, nfs, tftp

I have an NFS server connected to a reconfigurable computer (with a BORPH system). I'm using minicom with "run netboot" to boot via DHCP+TFTP+NFS, and I see the following error:

```
Sending DHCP requests .<6>eth0: link is up, 100 FDX, pause enabled
., OK
IP-Config: Got DHCP answer from 192.168.100.1, my address is 192.168.100.2
IP-Config: Complete:
     device=eth0, addr=192.168.100.2, mask=255.255.255.0, gw=192.168.100.1,
     host=roach030193, domain=, nis-domain=(none),
     bootserver=192.168.100.1, rootserver=192.168.100.1,
rootpath=/srv/roachboot/etch   

Looking up port of RPC 100003/2 on 192.168.100.1
rpcbind: server 192.168.100.1 not responding, timed out
Root-NFS: Unable to get nfsd port number from server, using default
Looking up port of RPC 100005/1 on 192.168.100.1
rpcbind: server 192.168.100.1 not responding, timed out
Root-NFS: Unable to get mountd port number from server, using default
mount: server 192.168.100.1 not responding, timed out
Root-NFS: Server returned error -5 while mounting /srv/roachboot/etch
VFS: Unable to mount root fs via NFS, trying floppy.
VFS: Cannot open root device "192.168.100.1:/srv/roachboot/etch" or
unknown-block(2,0)
Please append a correct "root=" boot option; here are the available 
partitions:
0100       4096 ram0 (driver?)
0101       4096 ram1 (driver?)
0102       4096 ram2 (driver?)
0103       4096 ram3 (driver?)
0104       4096 ram4 (driver?)
0105       4096 ram5 (driver?)
0106       4096 ram6 (driver?)
0107       4096 ram7 (driver?)
0108       4096 ram8 (driver?)
0109       4096 ram9 (driver?)
010a       4096 ram10 (driver?)
010b       4096 ram11 (driver?)
010c       4096 ram12 (driver?)
010d       4096 ram13 (driver?)
010e       4096 ram14 (driver?)
010f       4096 ram15 (driver?)
1f00       1792 mtdblock0 (driver?)
1f01        256 mtdblock1 (driver?)
1f02       8192 mtdblock2 (driver?)
1f03      54656 mtdblock3 (driver?)
1f04        256 mtdblock4 (driver?)
1f05        384 mtdblock5 (driver?)
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-
block(2,0)
```

When I disable the firewalls, in centos 6.5 with

```
service iptables stop
```

I see the following error

```
IP-Config: Got DHCP answer from 192.168.100.1, my address is 192.168.100.2
IP-Config: Complete:
     device=eth0, addr=192.168.100.2, mask=255.255.255.0, gw=192.168.100.1,
     host=roach030193, domain=, nis-domain=(none),
     bootserver=192.168.100.1, rootserver=192.168.100.1,
rootpath=/srv/roachboot/etch
Looking up port of RPC 100003/2 on 192.168.100.1
Looking up port of RPC 100005/1 on 192.168.100.1
VFS: Mounted root (nfs filesystem) readonly.
Freeing unused kernel memory: 136k init
Warning: unable to open an initial console.
warning: `ntpd' uses 32-bit capabilities (legacy support in use)
```

And then the console get stuck.